# TableView with Core Data: call saveAction from windowShouldClose

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, nstableview

I have a TableView bound to a Core Data entity and I have a saveAction method in my AppDelegate.

First I create a button to link to saveAction in AppDelegate. When I click the button the saveAction method gets fired just fine and the data is saved.

I want to trigger this same function when I close the window, so I create the following in AppDelagate:

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender{
    // Breakpoint here is reached.
    [self saveAction:sender];
    return true;
}
```

When I close the window, the breakpoint is reached, saveAction runs, but nothing is saved. The only difference that I can ascertain is that when the button is clicked, saveAction receives sender of NSButton, but when triggered through windowShouldCLose the sender is logged as NSWindow.

Is there anything I'm missing? Very new to all this so pretty likely. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had almost the same issue - fixed after adding that :

in interface builder, select the window you wish to control the "should close" feature, and open the connections inspector ... you must have a connection between your referencing outlet and the AppDelegate, but you must ALSO have a connection between the outlet named "Delegate" and the AppDelegate (in my case, i had only the 1st one by default, getting mad for days with this "should close" function, everything get suddenly OK after adding the 2nd one ...)